# Why div is not according to its height and width after position: Relative but works fine when adding semi-colon after relative?

Tags: html, css, css-position

https://codepen.io/nitishj/pen/yLXVNwa?editors=1100

Here,  when you add semi-colon the dimension of div works but not when semi-colon is not there.
I  also observed that it is responsive without semicolon.
What is the reasoning behind this? Can someone please answer this

```
div.Container

{   
 position:relative

   width:300px;
   height:300px;
  
   background:yellow;
}

div.PositionMe
{   
  position:absolute;

   top:10px;
   right:10px;
   width:20px;
   height:20px;
   background:red
}
```

Comment: The reason is that without semicolon, you are simply writing _invalid_ CSS. The parser does not know where one property value assignment ends, and the next begins - so both position and width will not apply here.

Answer (score 0):

When you do not put semicolon the parser is trying to interpret until it finds semicolon, in this case it tries this:

```
position: relative width:300px;
```

Of course that is not valid code for css, position can not be that, so it is not setting width and position of the div.

So, when you put it tries this:

```
position: relative;
width:300px;
```

And that is valid code, setting position to relative and width to 300 px.